# abrir nova janela php

Tags: php, javascript, redirecionamento

No site tenho vários banners publicitários. Ao clicar num banner, sou redireccionado para uma página que faz a contagem de cliques no banner. Depois desta contagem sou redireccionado para a página anterior ao clique no banner e é aberta uma nova aba com o link do banner. Para tal tenho o seguinte:

```
// $go_to_url é o link do banner
echo "<script>window.open('".$go_to_url."', '_blank');</script>";

// redirecciona para a página anterior ao clique no banner
$last_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo "<script>window.location.replace('".$last_url."');</script>";
```

Até aqui tudo bem, mas há um problema que pode acontecer, o browser pedir permissão para abrir janelas de pop-up, e neste caso o cliente não tem tempo de aceitar porque é logo redireccionado para a página anterior. Há alguma maneira de contornar este problema? Por exemplo ao usar a função header() do php, mas esta função não permite abrir outra aba.

Comment: Se o link do banner direcionar para uma nova e em seguida usar o header resolve seu problema?

Comment: se usar o header sou reencaminhado para fora do site e não é isso que quero. quero ficar no site e em outra aba seja aberta a página do banner

Comment: Foi exatamente isso que disse na resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bom dia, sugiro que a nova página seja aberta em outra janela e sua página fique no browser. Você pode fazer da seguinte forma: supondo que sua página é index.php

em sua página:

```
<a href="index.php?redir_to=<?php echo base64_encode($go_to_url); ?> target="_blank">">Banner</a>
```

no php faça o seguinte

```
<?php
    $redir_to = base64_decode($_GET['redir_to']);
    //GRAVAR O CONTADOR PARA $redir_to EM BD OU txt conforme seu caso

    header("Location: $redir_to");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra  alternativa seria fazer a contabilidade do click por ajax:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="<?php echo $go_to_url; ?>" class="anuncio" target="_blank">Anúncio</a>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.anuncio').click(function() {
    $.get('contabiliza.php', { url: $(this).attr('href') });
});
```

**PHP: contabiliza.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
// proceder com a contabilidade.
}
?>
```

A vantagem deste método é que o link fica totalmente transparente.

Comment: exacto, tambem seria uma alternativa viável! obrigado